# WP cron doesn't pass trough my arguments

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I've been trying to import some posts trough a cron action. The problem is my last step. Everything is going well, except for the execution of the cron. It is only passing trough the first argument.

Which would (clearly) point at the following code

```
add_action( 'import_videos_recurring', 'import_recurring', 10, 3 );
```

But if I execute the following code for testing purposes (simplified code). It will still pass me only one argument.

```
function import_recurring_3( $args ) {

    var_dump( $args );

}


function add_timething() {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'minutly', 'import_videos_recurring_3', array(
        'user' => 'testding',
        'value' =>'testwaarde',
        'break' => true
    ) );
}

add_action('init', 'add_timething');

add_action( 'import_videos_recurring_3', 'import_recurring_3', 10, 3 );
```

I've read a couple of questions & answers on the exchange here. But can't find why the following code is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

`function import_recurring_3( $args, $args2, $args3 ) {
    var_dump( $args );
    var_dump( $args2 );
    var_dump( $args3 );
}`

Comment: That works but only for the first call which is immediate (time()) any subsequent calls the parameter/s aren't passed. Any idea how to get the same parameter passed each time the scheduled call occurs?